# Rails URLs goes backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, simple-form

I am having a weird problem. I have two models in my app, downtowns and properties. Downtowns should have multiple properties and properties should have one downtown.

On my downtown show page i loop through the properties through each downtown and then offer links to these properties.

Problem is.....when i click on each property, the url goes backwards. IE, a downtown with an ID of 1 and a property with an ID of 8 should go

```
downtown/1/properties/8
```

yet it keeps going

```
downtown/8/properties/1
```

I think this is so weird and i have no clue what i've been doing wrong here.

On my downtown show page, i loop through each property

```
%h2= @downtown.name
- if @downtown.properties.present?
  %p 
    - @downtown.properties.collect do |property|
      = link_to property.name, downtown_property_path(property)

- else
  No downtowns for now.
```

My routes are the basic nested routing here

```
  resources :downtowns do
    resources :properties
  end
```

my properties controller is

```
class PropertiesController < Downtown::ApplicationController
  before_action :find_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @property = @downtown.properties.new
  end

  def create
    @property = @downtown.properties.new(property_params)

    if @property.save
      redirect_to @downtown
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name, :downtown, :downtown_id......)
  end

  def find_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My downtown controller is

```
class DowntownsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_downtown, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @properties = Property.where(downtown: @downtown_id)
  end

  def new
    @downtown = Downtown.new
  end

  def create
    @downtown = Downtown.create(downtown_params)
    if @downtown.save
      redirect_to @downtown
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def downtown_params
    params.require(:downtown).permit(:name, :city)
  end

  def find_downtown
    @downtown = Downtown.find(params[:id])
  end  
end
```

Finally in my properties form i have a polymorphic path

```
= simple_form_for([@property, @downtown]) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :last_remodel
  = f.input :original_construction_year
```

Comment: if it's a nested route it should probably have @downtown as the first argument : ```downtown_property_path(@downtown, property)```

Comment: I'd also recommend checking out the [Shallow Nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) section in the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested route path take multiple arguments [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).

In your case, it should be `downtown_property_path(@downtown, property)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide an answer that may simplify your routing.

If your properties can only reference one downtown (which seems to be the case according to your controllers), then you don't need to have URLs such as `downtown/1/properties/8`.

To access the property with id 8, you should simply go and use `properties/8`, since in the controller action, you'll be able to load the related downtown (with id=1) since it is referenced in the property record. The `show` action for a nested resource typically doesn't need to go through the parent.

PS: Accessing nested resources through the parent resource is mostly useful when the child resource (`properties` in your case) can have several parent resources linked to it (`downtowns`).